# Encode xml column values as xml in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a method that is taking vales directly from the database, building a string of xml and then writing the xml to a file.

This is fine until I get special characters eg "'", "<", "&" etc.

Does anyone know of something in Sql Server that would allow me to encode the values as i select them; for example;

```
select encode(service_status) from myTable
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your sql server version...

Comment: Owww! Really Sad! But can't you write down a small function in C# to do the same and add it on SQL Server?

Comment: I have added a reference to an excellent article showing to go about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to say what part is done in SQL Server and what part in the calling application. It's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have >= sql 2005, I think it may be easiest to stuff your value into an xml element and then pull it back out. This will entitize anything that needs encoding.

```
declare @x xml, @str varchar(8000), @encStr varchar(8000)
set @x = '<a/>'
set @str = '><&'

set @x.modify(
    'insert text{sql:variable("@str")}
    as first into (/a)[1]')

set @encStr = CAST(@x.query('/a/text()') as varchar(8000))
select @encStr
--returns: &gt;&lt;&amp;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `FOR XML` clause.

It can build `XML` from multiple values automatically:

```
WITH  q AS (
        SELECT  'Barnes & Noble' AS shop
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Marks & Spencer'
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE

---
<q shop="Barnes &amp; Noble" /><q shop="Marx &amp; Spencer" />
```

If you just want to encode an existing value, use:

```
SELECT  'Barnes & Noble'
FOR XML PATH('')

---
Barnes &amp; Noble
```

Comment: "FOR XML" exists in SQL 2000 too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx

Comment: @Mitch: I thought it was in 2005+ only, but @gbn's link changed my mind.

Comment: SQL 2005 added XPath/Xquery + xml datatype + generally made things better. No more "sp_xmlpreparedocument"!

Comment: That works if I want to build the xml directly in sql server, but I just want to encode the data - the xml is already being built within the application to which the query returns.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need the CLR either just do it in sql...

```
create function [dbo].[fn_XMLEscape]( @s varchar(max)) returns varchar(max)
as 
begin
  declare @rs varchar(max) 
  set @rs = @s
  set @rs = replace(@rs, '&', '&amp;')
  set @rs = replace(@rs, '''', '&apos;')
  set @rs = replace(@rs, '"', '&quot;')
  set @rs = replace(@rs, '>', '&gt;')
  set @rs = replace(@rs, '<', '&lt;')
  Return( @rs)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the calling application is building what you return into XML, then it is up to the calling application to encode the data. If you want to return XML from SQL Server, then it would be up to you, and the "FOR XML" answer by Quassnoi is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server version 2005/2008, then you are in luck, as you can create your own `ENCODE` function using [CLR Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx).

[A really good article can be found here](http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/clrfunctionforsqlserver.aspx).

Comment: I'm not using .net :( I'm using a BPM suite based on JAVA :( :( Otherwise that would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

My variant:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_XmlEncode (@STR varchar(200))
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX('&', @STR) > 0
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @POS1 int, @POS2 int
       SET @POS1 = CHARINDEX('&', @STR)
       WHILE @POS1 > 0 BEGIN
           IF SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS1, 5) <> '&'
              SET @STR = LEFT(@STR, @POS1 - 1) + '&' 
                  + case when @POS1 < LEN(@STR) THEN SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS1 + 1, LEN(@STR) - @POS1) ELSE '' END
           SET @POS2 = CHARINDEX('&', SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS1 + 5, LEN(@STR)))
           IF @POS2 = 0 BREAK
           SET @POS1 = @POS1 + 4 + @POS2
       END
    END
    WHILE CHARINDEX('<', @STR) > 0
       SET @STR = REPLACE(@STR, '<', '<')
    WHILE CHARINDEX('>', @STR) > 0
       SET @STR = REPLACE(@STR, '>', '>')
    RETURN @STR
END
GO
-- Tests
SELECT dbo.fn_XmlEncode('&&'), dbo.fn_XmlEncode('&<&>"&&')
```